# WPF : How to access observablecollection in a nested usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection

in my application I'm using two usercontrol : UserControl1 is the main one, inside it, I have UserControl2 used six times.

UserControl2 has several combobox, and I would like to fill them dynamically from the final application. As a start I'm trying to bind data to one of them.

The combobox in UserControl2 look like this :

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="VidTransform" Template="{DynamicResource BaseComboBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource BaseComboBoxItemStyle}" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.VidTransformsNames,ElementName=Ch_Parameters, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTransform,ElementName=Ch_Parameters, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

At the moment I'm only able to fill it manually, using this ObservableCollection (all strings shows up correctly) :

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _VidTransformsNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "test0", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" });
    public ObservableCollection<string> VidTransformsNames
    {
        get { return _VidTransformsNames; }
        set { _VidTransformsNames = value; }
    }
```

In UserControl1 (which contains UserControl2), I tried to create an other ObservableCollection and fill it dynamically at runtime in my final application.

Here it is :

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _VideoTransformsNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "Test0", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5" });
    public ObservableCollection<string> VideoTransformsNames
    {
        get { return _VideoTransformsNames; }
        set { _VideoTransformsNames = value; }
    }
```

And then binding :

```
<local:UserControl1 VidTransformsNames="{Binding Path=VideoTransformsNames, ElementName=cmix, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I'm beginner, but here I'm wrong for sure, as I get this error :

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'VidTransformsNames' property of type 'UserControl1'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How can I access and fill up at runtime the observablecollection of UserControl2 if it is nested in UserControl1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your property needs to be declared properly as `DependencyProperty`

> Dependency properties and the WPF property system extend property
>   functionality by providing a type that backs a property, as an
>   alternative implementation to the standard pattern of backing the
>   property with a private field. The name of this type is
>   DependencyProperty. The other important type that defines the WPF
>   property system is DependencyObject. DependencyObject defines the base
>   class that can register and own a dependency property.

Please follow this https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753358(v=vs.100).aspx, or Dependency Property Overview https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx

Example taken from above articles:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),


...


    );
public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

Let's try to set it to your code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoTransformsNamesProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("VideoTransformsNames", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(UserControl1));

public string VideoTransformsNames
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(VideoTransformsNamesProperty) as ObservableCollection<string>;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(VideoTransformsNamesProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What property are you talking about exactly ? should I use DependencyProperty instead of ObservableCollection ?

Comment: You have to create `public static readonly DependecyProperty YourName` and then register it correctly. In register part you will have to add in your case `typeof(ObservableCollection<T>)`

Comment: indeed, this is working now. I didn't know observablecollection could be a type of dependencyproperty. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please mark my answer as correct.